# Mysql status with same interest

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on an app and i am using mysql as my backend. I have two tables

```
---------                -------
tags                      status 
---------                ---------
tagsID                  statusID
userID                    userID
statusID                  status
tag
```

I am trying to list status with their corresponding tags. I tried this query but it doesnt' work.

```
SELECT soc_status.status , tags.tag FROM soc_status JOIN tags
ON soc_status.statusID= tags.tagsID;
```

this is the result i am getting

```
    ---------------     --------             
    status               tags
    ----------------     --------
    hello how are you  , Television
    hello how are you  ,  Music
```

Here you can see the status is duplicating. i want the tags in the same column. And How to get the statuses of users which matches the tags of the user who is using the app . Any ideas ?

Comment: `SELECT soc_status.status , group_concat(tags.tag) FROM soc_status JOIN tags ON soc_status.statusID= tags.tagsID group by soc_status.status`

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: @splash58 it gives me the following result. "hello how are you","Television,Music"
"it was a great day","Television,Music" .How can i get the status of users which has the same interest of the user A (I mean the user who's using the app).